# Eclipse text render issue

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am using Eclipse Neon2 on Mac. Text in code editor has render problem and overlaps on scroll. When I select all the text (cmd+a) it re renders and solves the problem. But when I re scroll it overlaps again.

I couldn't find a solution on internet.

How can I solve this.

Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: All editors? Just the Java Editor? On all files? Just this file?

Comment: On all files java, xml, text,...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in Eclipse [489383](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489383). There are plenty of similar issues were reported and closed as duplicated, but this one is still open and, as I understand, targeted for version 4.6. There is a simple workaround that has helped in some cases (in mine it did help): `export GTK3=0` before starting eclipse.